# How to join multiple data sources together in Cassandra

Tags: join, cassandra, datasource, modeling

I have multiple data sources from RDBMS that need to be pushed to Cassandra as the common data layer; each of these data sources have different fields, and there is no common global ID across them. Rather, a global unique ID is made of a composite of multiple fields.
How to model this in Cassandra in order to populate the data ?

If I create a C* table with all the fields:

> Create table T(datasrc1_uid uuid, datasrc1_field1 text,
>   datasrc1_field2 text, ..,  datasrc2_uid uuid,datasrc2_field1 text,
>   datasrc2_field2 text,  PRIMARY KEY (datasrc1_uid, datasrc2_uid);

To insert/update in T i would have to open up connections to both datasrc1 and datasrc2 at the same time, and essentially construct/join in the application layer. 
Otherwise, i could create separate tables for each of the data source (and there are more than 2, this is just an example!):

> Create table DS1(datasrc1_uid uuid, datasrc1_field1 text, ..
>     PRIMARY KEY (datasrc1_uid, datasrc1_field1, ..);
>   Create table DS2(datasrc2_uid uuid, datasrc2_field1 text, ..
>     PRIMARY KEY (datasrc2_uid, datasrc2_field1, ..);

Then again join at the application layer (and use a BATCH statement to keep inserts/updates atomic), which is hard because these would have to be done step by step instead of a single Join statement, keeping some data in memory, etc. This would have been possible with an RDBMS via a simple join between DS1/DS2 ..
Any other way to model this ?

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb - model your tables based on queries. Write data in many C* tables, if you need, to be able to read from a single one, one per query.

There is a good course available at https://datastaxacademy.elogiclearning.com/

Comment: I agree that modeling tables should be based on queries - but my queries will be around getting data from all these fields joined together ..

Comment: Then write all the fields you need in a single table

Comment: Well, that is the problem - not all of the fields are available at once; so i can do an insert from DataSource1 which will populate a few fields, but then i need to somehow join with Datasource2 to populate the other remaining fields..